# Bootstrap continual thumbnail list into grid

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want to make a long list of elements, images for example that will be added into the grid which width is `span12` and every elements width should be `span3`, that makes 4 elements in 1 row.

The problem is, when I list all the elements or I make a php function that lists them Boostrap thinks I want to put it in one row, but I don't. I want to make a new row every 4 elements or so... I want to be able to add as many `<li>` as I want and not worry about where another row should be.. What should I do ?

This is what happened to me, the 5th image has wrong margin on the left side. I want to make it in the same position as images in the first row.

[Screenshot here](http://prntscr.com/17bafa)

I use this php logic to echo out pictures

```
  $dir = "../img";

    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if (preg_match("/.jpg/", $file)) {

                    echo "<li class='span3'>
                            <a href='$dir/$file' class='thumbnail'>
                              <img src='$dir/$file'>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                          ";   
               }
            }
           closedir($dh);
       }
    }
```

And I have no idea on how to post a new row each 4th picture or so.

Row is marked as `<div class='row-fluid'>`

Answer (score 0):

That's a common problem, and I think there's no elegant solution. Consider one of these approachings.

**Solution 1** Review your iteration logic

If refactoring your PHP logic is an option, try to render a `row` each 4 elements (I can't suggest an specific code without viewing your current logic).

**EDIT**

The code for a while loop could be as follows:

```
<?php
$count = 1;
echo '<div class="row">';
while (your_condition) {
    echo '<div class="span3">your_content</div>';
    if ($count % 4 == 0) {
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }
    $count++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

**Solution 2** Hack the fifth element's margin

Correct the margin-left of the affected elements, so you don't need to respect the native Bootstrap markup.

```
.thumbnails .span4:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, that code is not compatible with Internet Explorer, so maybe you'll have to find a JavaScript or jQuery solution.

Comment: my current php logic :

`if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                    if (preg_match("/.jpg/", $file)) {
                      
                        echo "<li class='span3'>
                                <a href='$dir/$file' class='thumbnail'>
                                  <img src='$dir/$file'>
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              ";   
                   }
                }
               closedir($dh);
           }
        }`

Comment: I've added sample code for a while loop. It's generic to not localize too much the answer, but the count and modulus (%) logic is the same.